# Update a slice or column in tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to update a whole column no matter the shape of the tensor, also the index of the column can be anything within the shape range.

```
 tensor = tf.Variable(tf.ones((5,5)))
```

I am trying to achieve this numpy operation:

```
 tensor[:,2] = 0

 [ 1 1 0 1 1 ]
 [ 1 1 0 1 1 ]
 [ 1 1 0 1 1 ]
 [ 1 1 0 1 1 ]
 [ 1 1 0 1 1 ]
```

I tried using tf.scatter_update but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating a new tensor, you could try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.Variable(tf.ones((5,5)))
s0, s1, s2 = tf.split(t, [2, 1, 2], axis=1)
s = tf.concat([s0,tf.zeros((5,1)),s2], axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    y = sess.run(s)
    print(y)
```

Comment: I considered this way, but the problem is as I stated, I want it to work with any shape.

Comment: and to pick any column.